# Production crash log in iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, crash

MY crash log says this with no information. Using atos command I get this info saying that specialized UnsafeBufferPointer.count.getter in loginviewcontroller. Any idea why this crash is caused?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010
VM Region Info: 0x10 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4340006896
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                 0000000102af4000-0000000102af8000 

Thread 7 name:
Thread 7 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001821e4430 objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                           0x000000018c543d90 -[UIWindowLayer actionForKey:] + 80 (UIWindow.m:432)
2   QuartzCore                      0x0000000186fcb984 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 244 (CALayer.mm:9308)
3   QuartzCore                      0x0000000186fcfad0 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 332 (CALayer.mm:9182)
4   QuartzCore                      0x0000000186f3c31c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 336 (CALayer.mm:2416)
5   QuartzCore                      0x0000000186f63b40 CA::Transaction::commit() + 540 (CATransactionInternal.mm:425)
6   QuartzCore                      0x0000000186f64980 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92 (CATransactionInternal.mm:795)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182f2ecdc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32 (CFRunLoop.c:1824)
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182f2c694 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412 (CFRunLoop.c:1934)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182e4cc78 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 468 (CFRunLoop.c:3247)
10  WebCore                         0x000000018adc184c RunWebThread(void*) + 560 (WebCoreThread.mm:690)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182bb02b4 _pthread_body + 308 (pthread.c:740)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182bb0180 _pthread_start + 312 (pthread.c:799)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182baeb74 thread_start + 4
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like heap corruption. Likely a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer]). Basically, `-[UIWindowLayer actionForKey:]` is interacting with a pointer to something that is not longer pointer to a valid object. This is an extremely common cause of crashes within `objc_msgSend`.

I'm afraid to say that this report isn't likely to reveal the cause. It's very common for the **cause** of a dangling pointer to occur at a different time than the resulting crash (**effect**). Because of this, there's a very low likelihood that the captured stack trace will reveal anything about why this pointer is no longer valid.

What I generally recommend in this situations:

- Look for other crashes that look heap-corruption-related (more in `objc_msgSend`, for example)
- Try out `Zombies` in Instruments
- Try malloc scribble, or guardmalloc, two other good memory debugging tools

It's hard, and often even impossible, to reason about heap corruption. So, just try to find and fix as many issues as you can. It's totally possible that one of them is responsible for a variety of crashes, one of which could be this one.

Good luck!